# How to print spades, hearts, diamonds, etc. in python

Tags: python

try to print heart sign using unit code:
print("\U0002660")
this sign should be an heart sign but don't work

Comment: You can use `print(chr(0x2665))`. Alternatively: `print("♥")` which is easier to understand in your code. (2660 is a spade).

Comment: great! that works thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From python documentation.

> The default encoding for Python source code is UTF-8, so you can
> simply include a Unicode character in a string literal:
>
> Python 3 also supports using Unicode characters in
> identifiers
>
> If you can’t enter a particular character in your editor or want to
> keep the source code ASCII-only for some reason, you can also use
> escape sequences in string literals. (Depending on your system, you
> may see the actual capital-delta glyph instead of a u escape.)

```
>>> "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"  # Using the character name
'\u0394'
>>> "\u0394"                          # Using a 16-bit hex value
'\u0394'
>>> "\U00000394"                      # Using a 32-bit hex value
'\u0394'
```

So we can straightaway print the Unicode characters like

```
print("♠")
```

In your case, you are trying to print "♠" using a 32-bit hex value. But you missed one 0.

The correct way is

```
print("\U00002660")
```

Comment: This is the start of a good answer, but "code only" answers are discouraged. Can you add some explanation perhaps explaining why this works but `print("\U0002660")` does not?

Comment: Thank you @JonSg for the suggestion. I have added an explanation